# Go "from zero to hero", usage and origin

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-origin

The expression  ***[from zero to hero](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+from+zero+to+hero)*** is an informal saying that means:

> - To change an outcome, one's situation, or oneself from being particularly unsuccessful, negative, unfortunate, or unpopular to being especially successful, positive, fortunate, or popular.
>
>   - *After his parents won the lottery, John went from zero to hero in his high school overnight. With computer programming becoming an increasingly in-demand skill, many who might have been picked on in high school are now going from zeros to heroes.* (TFD)

The expression is a quite common one and it is used in different contexts like [music](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Zero_to_Hero) and [tv programs](http://www.originsfightpromotions.com.au/node/128) for instance.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20zero%20to%20hero&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20zero%20to%20hero%3B%2Cc0)*** shows that "from zero to hero" became a popular expression especially from the early '90s.

Curiously the ODO has an entry for its opposite ***[from hero to zero](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/from-hero-to-zero)*** , which is  used to refer to a sudden, rapid decline in popularity or success.

Questions:

- When and by whom was the expression 'from zero to hero" first used?
- Who or what made it popular during the '90s? a song or a sports program for instance?

Comment: I'd be curious to know who first coined the phrase ditch the zero and get with this hero, while we are at it. :)

Comment: In Australia this is a colloquial term to refer to an idiot in a souped up car gunning it often from a traffic light. Some often time followed by a car wreck.

Comment: [Hercules (1997)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa0lMzaljTk) is where I first remember it :-)

Comment: None of the answers mention it yet, but no doubt the expression evolved out of car ads touting things like "Zero to Sixty in 2.8 seconds."  (And in agreement with @MonkeyZeus- I am certain that Disney's Hercules is what made it popular.)

Comment: @cobaltduck - not sure about the car ads since early usage instances are from the 19th century as shown in one answer, but the Hercules hypothesis is an interesting  indication.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus see that's what I said, too, and then the question got [deleted](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341216/go-from-zero-to-hero-usage-and-origin) and reasked.

Comment: @cobaltduck I'm in agreement with me too :-). If you look closely at the Ngram posted by Josh61 then you will see an uptick around 1994 but 1997 and later it just skyrockets. Although, if you change the "smoothing" to 0 then the real climb doesn't start till about 2000.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus came here for the hercules. _ZERO TO HERO, JUST LIKE /THAT/_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Regarding who made "from zero to hero" popular during the 90s.

This phrase was used as the [tagline](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110475/taglines?ref_=tt_ql_stry_1) of the 1994 movie *The Mask*, starring Jim Carrey.

The tagline is visible in this movie poster:

[image]

It is also featured prominently on lots of *The Mask* merchandise, evinced by [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20mask%20from%20zero%20to%20hero&biw=1594&bih=830&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil-qWt-6jOAhWBVxQKHV9_BlEQ_AUIBygC&dpr=1) Google image search. As you can see, it is featured prominently below the title on all sorts of toys and copies of the film.

The phrase is not, however, actually uttered in the film, evidenced by this [script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/m/mask-script-transcript-jim-carrey.html).

This film was very successful, with Wikipedia observing that it was ["the second-highest grossing superhero movie at that time, behind Batman"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mask_(film)).

Perhaps the popularity of this film had to do with the increased usage of the expression in the 90s. Two of the Google Books [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22from%20zero%20to%20hero%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:1997&lr=lang_en) from 1991-1997, which are used in plotting the ngram, actually reference the movie directly.

There is no question, however, whether this phrase was in use prior to the film: It certainly was. But tracking down its origin is a project for somebody else.

Comment: I personally never knew this phrase was used in The Mask; I cannot recall it being spoken during the movie at least. The animated film [Hercules (1997)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa0lMzaljTk) is what made the phrase memorable for me. +1 anyways :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: It's *not* used in the movie itself, as this answer points out.  Just in the marketing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well I feel foolish, I must have missed that statement when I read this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

SUPPLEMENTARY TO Silenus' ANSWER:
The earliest instance of "zero to hero" I find in Google Books is from 1893, on page 5 of an ["Address Before the Second Biennial Convention of the World's Woman's Christian Temperance Union and the Twentieth Annual Convention of the National Woman's Christian Temperance Union"](https://books.google.com/books?id=7xx47uURVTUC&pg=PA41&dq=%22zero+to+hero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR67vYg6nOAhVG9IMKHSlSBHQQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22zero%20to%20hero%22&f=false) by the WCTU president and women's suffragist Frances E. Willard:

> The history of the reformer, whether man or woman, on any line of action is but this: when he sees it all alone he is a fanatic ; when a good many see it with him they are enthusiasts ; when all see it is he is a hero. The gradations are as clearly marked by which he ascends from zero to hero, as the lines of latitude from the North Pole to the Equator.

DavePhD, however, has found an earlier use of "zero" paired with "hero" in [*Caïssa Rediviva: or, The Muzio Gambit.An Heroi-Comical Poem*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ni4VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22Farewell,+brave+hero,+Warrior,+farewell,+Reduced+to+zero+By+Macdonnell+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ9M3dw6rOAhWs6oMKHRVgASsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Farewell%2C%20brave%20hero%2C%20Warrior%2C%20farewell%2C%20Reduced%20to%20zero%20By%20Macdonnell%20%22&f=false) by An Amateur of Chess, 1836:

> Farewell, brave hero,
>    Warrior, farewell,
>   Reduced to zero
>    By Macdonnell

Comment: Earlier (1836) there was a chorus "Farewell, brave hero, Warrior, farewell, Reduced to zero By Macdonnell" (referring to the chess player MacDonnell) https://books.google.com/books?id=ni4VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22Farewell,+brave+hero,+Warrior,+farewell,+Reduced+to+zero+By+Macdonnell+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ9M3dw6rOAhWs6oMKHRVgASsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Farewell%2C%20brave%20hero%2C%20Warrior%2C%20farewell%2C%20Reduced%20to%20zero%20By%20Macdonnell%20%22&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD Wow. I'll incorporate that.

Comment: @StoneyB - why does your answer appear as a "community wiki" one?

Comment: @Josh61 I set it that way because it's only a partial answer; and because it's supplementary to another answer; and because I anticipated (rightly, it has proved) that earlier matter of relevance might come to light.

Comment: Now that's what I call actual research!

Comment: @SpencerWilliams Google Books is yoooogely yoooseful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to @Jonathan Piccirilli comment about the origin of "***ditch that zero and get with this hero***", it appears that the expression was made popular by ***the  1991 musical comedy ["Cool as Ice"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_as_Ice)*** where the main character Johnny " says  ***[drop that zero and get with this hero](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R1MxGFncZgQ)"***  to Kathy, trying to convince her to leave her boyfrind (a loser) for him (a hero).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s worth noting that the trailer for the 1985 John Hughes movie “Weird Science” used the following tag line:

“They went from zeroes to heroes in one fantastic weekend.”